# Apache Beam - BigQueryIO read Projection

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a Dataflow pipeline that reads from a BigQuery table. However, when reading the data, there is no other option than to read all records with the [read(SerializableFunction)](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#read-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction-) or the [readTableRows()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#readTableRows--) methods.
I was wondering, when using these methods, is there an option to provide a column-like projection (similar to the HBaseIO Scan [addColumn()](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#addColumn-byte:A-byte:A-) filter).

I know that there is the option of performing a query when loading data from BigQuery (using the [readTableRows().fromQuery()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.TypedRead.html#fromQuery-java.lang.String-)), but I'm wondering if there is a similar option to do projection like possible in HBaseIO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now, fromQuery() is the only option, but this may change in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, hope this will be added in the future :)